# Identity AuthenticationManager with unity.mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-identity, unity-container

I'm implementing dependency injection to an existing asp.net MVC website that uses identity for login.

**User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is always false**

I installed NuGet package: `Install-Package Unity.Mvc`

Added the following code in Unity.Config

```
container.RegisterType<ApplicationDbContext>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
                container.RegisterType<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
                container.RegisterType<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, UserStore<ApplicationUser>>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
    
                var accountInjectionConstructor = new InjectionConstructor(new ApplicationDbContext());
                container.RegisterType<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, UserStore<ApplicationUser>>(accountInjectionConstructor);
    
                container.RegisterType<IAuthenticationManager>(new InjectionFactory(o => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication));
```

AccountController constructor

```
private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager;
            private readonly IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager;   
     public AccountController(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> userStore, IAuthenticationManager authManager)
                {
                    UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);
                    AuthenticationManager = authManager;
                }
```

method to sign in

```
private async Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent)
            {
                AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
                var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie); //identity.IsAuthenticated is true
                AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity); //User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is false
            }
```

**Issue:**
Please check above commented lines, identity.IsAuthenticated is true (that's fine) but User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is still false.

***How to update this identity in HttpContext.User.Identity?***

Answer (score 0):

`ConfigureAuth()` in `startup.Auth.cs` was not being called. Calling this function fixed the issue